# Is a Masters year 1 in France the equivalent of a UK Masters?

Tags: masters, university, united-kingdom, degree, france

I am currently in the final year of my undergrad degree in the UK. I would love to do a year-long master's in France. I have realised their masters are two years long.

Would it be worthwhile doing the first year of a master's in France and would that be the equivalent to gaining a Master's in the UK or would I need to complete both years?

Comment: Why not just do the full two years in France?

Comment: Masters in France generally last 2 years, with courses the first 1.5 year, and a research project in a lab the last half year.  In many fields, the research project is often the starting point for a PhD.